# Implementing AdMob with lots of View Controllers

Tags: ios, admob

I'm sorry for this newbie question but here it goes.  I'm just starting with iOS and implementing AdMob in my app. The app is running fine with the Ads working but I have four View Controllers and for the sake of test I just implement all theses methods in all View Controllers.

```
- (GADRequest *)createRequest
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
```

But imagine if I had 100 VC...There's a way to do it only in one file and import like a .h file? Yes, my OOP knowledge is limited and If somebody can help me I would appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tutorial](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html) on implementing a singleton for ads, but you'd still need to implement the listener methods (if you want them) for each View Controller because you may need to react differently in different situations.

Personally, I think it's cleaner to just have those methods in each of your VC that have ads, and reconsider which VCs need ads in them. Your title screen and options screen aren't great candidates - a best practice is to only put ads in VCs where your users will spend most of their time.

Answer (score 0):

Just read your question and since it hasn't been answered yet, I would like to share my solution.

Create a ViewController that would act as base view controller for the rest of VCs. Implement the functions and listeners for ads in that base view controller and extend (inherit) rest of the VCs from this baseVC. Do all the work in the baseVC functions and if you need to add something different in a specific VC, you can do that and then call super of that function.

Hope this helps.